# check the height of another directive, angular js

Tags: angularjs

using angular js, how can you get the height of another directive (directive 2) and set the current elements height (directive 1) based upon that? I tried to use a broadcast in directive 2's link function, but elem[0].offsetHeight turned up as undefined when directive 1 received it.

Comment: any chance you could solve with the appropriate css?

Comment: Not sure how to with pure Css